# Appending to a nested list

Tags: python, nested-lists

I'm using a nested list to look up values in a dictionary I created.  I then want to append the values found to a list.  The problem I don't know how to code is how to I keep the values appended within the same nested list structure?  Here's the code where the last line I'm appending the values to an empty list.

```
#Creating a dictionary of FID: LU_Codes from external txt file
import sys, arcpy, string, csv

text_file = open("H:\SWAT\NC\FID_Whole.txt", "r")
Lines = text_file.readlines()
text_file.close()

FID_LU = map(string.split, Lines)
#print FID_LU
FID_GC_dict = dict(FID_LU)

Neighbors_file = open("H:\SWAT\NC\Sh_Neighbors2.txt","r")
Entries = Neighbors_file.readlines()
Neighbors_file.close()

Neighbors_List = map(string.split, Entries)

print Neighbors_List

#FID = [x[0] for x in Neighbors_List]
#print FID

gridList = []
for list in Neighbors_List:
    for item in list:
       #print FID_GC_dict[item]
       gridList.append(int(FID_GC_dict[item]))


 print gridList
```

Here's the output for Neighbors List (correct):

```
[['0', '1', '11', '12', '13'], ['1', '0', '2', '12', '13', '14'], ['2', '1', '3', '13', '14', '15'], ['3', '2', '4', '14', '15', '16'], ['4', '3', '5', '15', '16', '17'], ['5', '4', '6', '16', '17', '18'], ['6', '5', '7', '17', '18', '19'], ['7', '6', '8', '18', '19', '20'], ['8', '7', '9', '19', '20', '21'], ['9', '8', '20', '21', '22'], ['10', '11']]
```

Here's the output for gridList (incorrect):

```
[3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4]
```

What I would like gridList to look like is:

```
[[3, 3, 4, 4, 4], [3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4], [3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 2], [3, 3, 3, 4, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3], [3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3], [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3], [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3], [3, 3, 3, 3, 3], [3, 4]]
```

Any help would be appreciated.  I'm new to python...reading the posts helps, but I'm struggling with this one.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make a temporary list, `row`. Append the items from the inner loop to `row`, and then in the outer loop, append the row to `gridList`:

```
gridList = []
for nlist in Neighbors_List:
    row = []
    for item in nlist:
       row.append(int(FID_GC_dict[item]))
    gridList.append(row)
```

Note that you could also use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) here:

```
gridList = [[int(FID_GC_dict[item]) for item in nlist] 
            for nlist in Neighbors_List]
```

PS. It is best not to name a variable `list`, since it shadows the builtin type of the same name.

Answer (score 1):

You're appending to a single list.  Try this

```
gridList = []
for list in Neighbors_List:
    temp = []
    for item in list:
       #print FID_GC_dict[item]
       temp.append(int(FID_GC_dict[item]))
    gridList.append(temp)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
gridList = [int(FID_GC_dict[item]) for item in l for l in Neighbors_List]
```

Python's [list comprehensions](http://carlgroner.me/Python/2011/11/09/An-Introduction-to-List-Comprehensions-in-Python.html) are awesome.  Learn them, love them.  (note this returns a list of tuples, if you want a list of lists, you can nest comprehensions.

Also, do not use `list` as a variable name, as it conflicts with the builtin [list](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#list)