# Merge two arrays into an list of arrays

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, jupyter

Hi I am trying compile a bunch of arrays that I have in a dictionary using a for loop and I cant seem to find proper solution for this.

Essentially what I have in a simplified form:

```
dict['w1']=[1,2,3]
dict['w2']=[4,5,6]
dict['w3']=[7,8]

x = []
for i in range(3):
    x = np.concatenate([x],[dict['w'+str(i+1)].values],axis=0)
```

what it gives:

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

what I want:

```
x = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[6,7]]
```

I want to use the for loop because I have too many arrays to 'compile' and cant key in them one by one would be very inefficient. This way I can use the created array to plot a boxplot directly.

A simiiliar question exists with no loop requirement but still does not have proper solution. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12020872/array-of-arrays-python-numpy)

Comment: You won't be able to achieve that solution with a numpy array, all column and rows have to be the same size in a np.array. That being said you seem to be confusing numpy arrays and python lists they are not the same, so don't use numpy functions (wich work on arrays) if you only use lists.

Comment: Last element of expected o/p has to be `[7,8]` instead, right?

Comment: Also, I sensed that you are looking to avoid loop from your question's other parts, except at this line : `"I want to use the for loop ..."`. Typo there?

Comment: I'm removing the `duplicate`; the answers in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9285414/appending-to-a-nested-list are inferior to the answers already given (and accepted) here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comprehension:

```
# using name as "dict" is not proper use "_dict" otherwise.
dict['w1']=[1,2,3]
dict['w2']=[4,5,6]
dict['w3']=[7,8]

x = [dict["w"+str(i)] for i in range(1, 4)]
```

gives output:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8]]
```

Comment: This works like a charm! I have a question though. I have the keys in the dict as 'w01', 'w02'.......'w10'. So there is slight issue when its hits the value '10'. Is it possible to include a 'if' into the code u have written above?

Comment: You can use condition in Comprehensions, it'll go something like `[x1 for x1 in something if condition == True else x2]`.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to get the argsort indices based on the keys and sort the elements/values out of the dictionary using those indices, like so -

```
np.take(dict.values(),np.argsort(dict.keys()))
```

If you need a list as the output, add [`.tolist()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html).

Sample run -

```
In [84]: dict
Out[84]: {'w1': [4, 8, 2, 1], 'w2': [1, 3, 8], 'w3': [3, 2]}

In [85]: np.take(dict.values(),np.argsort(dict.keys()))
Out[85]: array([[4, 8, 2, 1], [1, 3, 8], [3, 2]], dtype=object)

In [86]: np.take(dict.values(),np.argsort(dict.keys())).tolist()
Out[86]: [[4, 8, 2, 1], [1, 3, 8], [3, 2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just `append` the item to the list. Note, BTW, that `range` starts with `0` if you don't specify the start value and treats the end value as an **exclusive** border:

```
x = []
for i in range(1, 4):
    x.append(dict['w' + str(i)])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean lists and not dictionarys, then you're looking for the zip command.

Zip (w1,w2,w3)