# Append columns to the beginning and end of a 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, append

I would like to take two 1D arrays

```
Ne_initial = Ne[:,0]
Ne_final = Ne[:,-1]
```

and append them to an existing 2D array as the first (Ne_initial) and last (Ne_final) rows. I am unsure how to do this. Can anyone help?

Comment: look at .append and .insert methods

Comment: @roganjosh all arrays are numpy.arrays

Comment: @Ywapom could you use either of those to cleanly create a new "column" in a python nested list?

Comment: @roganjosh yes, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9285414/appending-to-a-nested-list

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add an extra column to a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8486294/how-to-add-an-extra-column-to-a-numpy-array)

Comment: `np.c_[Ne_initial, other, Ne_final]`

Comment: It is different from the duplicate, once you've clarified rows and columns. If the case is just to add rows then I'm curious about any efforts you've made to solve this problem.

Comment: @roganjosh I've attempted np.insert for the first and np.append for the last, but I am getting "ValueError: array is not broadcastable to correct shape"

Comment: Update: problem solved using @mad_ 's method, with a bit of reshaping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy as np 
a = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]]) 

print 'First array:' 
print a 
print '\n'  
b = np.array([[5,6],[7,8]]) 

print 'Second array:' 
print b 
print '\n'

print 'Vertical stacking:' 
c = np.vstack((a,b)) 
print c # creating a 2-D array
col1=np.array([2,3,4,5])
col2=np.array([1,1,1,1])
d=np.column_stack((a1,b2))
np.concatenate((d,c)) # adding back to existing array
```

Comment: I had to tweak your answer a bit for it to work: instead of np.vstack I had to use np.hstack, and for it to work properly I had to reshape the initial and final 1D arrays so that their shapes were (#,1) instead of (#,). with those edits, this works!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
my_2d_array = []

my_2d_array.insert(0, Ne_initial)
my_2d_array.append(Ne_final)
```

Comment: That only works if the 2D array is empty, which it isnt. My question is more so how to add these two 1D arrays to the beginning and then the end of the pre-existing 2D array

Comment: this method also does not work if objects are not lists. My objects are np.arrays, not lists.

Answer (score 0):

The following example should accomplish what you want:

IN:

```
import numpy as np

existing2Darray = np.matrix([[8, 3, 6, 1],[2, 5, 4, 2],[7, 2, 5, 1]])
Ne_initial = existing2Darray[:,0]
Ne_last = existing2Darray[:,-1]
```

OUT:

```
 [[8 3 6 1]
 [2 5 4 2]
 [7 2 5 1]]

[[8]
 [2]
 [7]]

[[1]
 [2]
 [1]]
```

IN:

```
np.append(existing2Darray, Ne_initial, axis=1))
```

OUT:

```
[[8 3 6 1 8]
 [2 5 4 2 2]
 [7 2 5 1 7]]
```

IN:

```
np.insert(existing2Darray, [0], Ne_last, axis=1))
```

OUT:

```
[[1 8 3 6 1]
 [2 2 5 4 2]
 [1 7 2 5 1]]
```